# Port forwarding/bypass firewall

Tags: networking, server, ssh, mysql, firewall

I have two servers located at two different places:
Ubuntu Server (MySQL)
Ubuntu Server (Tomcat)

The problem here is that the Tomcat server cant send data to the mySQL server over port 7878 because it's behind a firewall.

I can SSH to both of the servers. How can I allow the tomcat server behind the firewall to be able to send data to the MySQL with port forwarding/ssh tunnel? I've read about the conecepts but I just can't seem to grasp my head around it, hence me asking for practical help and explanation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: upon re-reading your question I surmise that your server is behind a firewall that you do not control? If so, please disregard the iptables part of the answer and skip to the SSH config part...

Is it a matter of wanting the transport to be encrypted, or is it simply a matter of getting through the firewall?

Getting through the firewall could be as simple as adding something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s aa.bb.cc.dd/32 --dport 7878 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If you're looking for a good resource on configuring an SSH connection take a look here: http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

There's too much to be said on the subject to hash it all out here.

Once you have the basic ssh config set up it should be relatively trivial to create a script to start the connection (including a forwarded port) which could for example be executed when your network interface comes up, similar to the way a lot of people have their iptables rules loaded.
Take a look in /etc/network/if-up.d/ (off the top of my head) for examples.

Hope this gets you started!

Comment: I got started with this command: ssh -f -N -L 7878:127.0.0.1:7878 root@tmysqlServer 
Meaning everything localhost:7878 will be sent to the MySQL server.

Comment: Will this enable the tomcat to access the MySQL through the firewall? Have a created an SSH tunnel?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, localhost:7878 now tunnels traffic to the remote system:7878.

If you execute this command on the system Tomcat is on you should be able to point it to localhost:7878 and it should "just work".